# How to determine non-Ascii chars in string

Tags: php

I need to validate a string to ensure it uses only ASCII.  Is there a PHP function that will return whether or not a character is ASCII?

Comment: [`mb_check_encoding`](http://PHP.net/mb_check_encoding)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pattern matching `preg_match()` This searches the string for the pattern and returns true if match is successful, else false.

In this example,

```
$string = 'stack overflow Ã';
if(!preg_match( '/[\\x80-\\xff]+/',$string))
echo 'Valid ASCII';
else 
echo 'Invalid ASCII';
```

Source: http://pageconfig.com/post/how-to-validate-ascii-text-in-php

Answer (score 1):

```
if(preg_match('/[^\x20-\x7f]/', $string))
```